# Is there a cost for a Service Principal that is only to be used with Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, cost-management

I have searched for, but have been able to find anything related to costs when it comes to service principals. I want to set up builds, tests and deployments in Azure DevOps, but the I want to be able to calculate the potential costs.

Maybe its only the actions inside Azure DevOps that adds any costs and not the service principal itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service principals don't cost anything. Certain tiers of Azure AD (which service principals are created in) do cost money. The resources you deploy within Azure will definitely cost something

Comment: Today Azure DevOps supports service principals as users. These get charged the regular user license costs.